# Does current metaphysics answer Jacobi's critique of foundationalism?

Tags: metaphysics, foundationalism

F. H. Jacobi ([Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedrich_Heinrich_Jacobi?wprov=sfla1)) argued in the late 18th century against Kant that any foundation of knowledge will inevitably lead to an infinite regression of justifications (thus any foundation of knowledge will eventually lead to nihilism).

I know that many Neo-Kantians have tried (sometimes successfully) to "fix" this issue in Kant's philosophy (Kant himself tried in Opus Postumum). But I haven't heard of that in the 20th (and 21th) philosophy of metaphysics. So, was it just taken for granted after the Neo-Kantians' solutions? Was it ignored? Or was it discussed and I just haven't seen this discussion (and hopefully will get references if this is the correct option)?

Comment: There's no need to look to Neo-Kantians or anyone else for that matter, because Kant himself addressed this question. The foundation of knowledge would lead to an infinite regress *if* it weren't grounded in God as the original source of reason. Kant asserted, "For the greatest systematic and purposive unity, which your reason demands as a regulative principle to ground all investigation of nature, was precisely what justified you in making the idea of a highest intelligence." (A699/B727) So without God, there would be no possibility for knowledge.

Comment: Furthermore, if Jacobi had understood Kant's argument concerning the antinomies of reason, he would have realized that his infinite-regress argument was a moot point which Kant had already carefully worked out in the *Critique of Pure Reason*. Therefore, there never was any issue that would have needed fixing in *Opus Postumum*, nor is there anything for modern philosophers to defend which Kant hasn't adequately defended himself.

Comment: @PédeLeão and what if we don't want to base knowledge in God?

Comment: You're free to base your philosophy on whatever makes you happy. However, John Maynard Keynes expressed the fundamental principle that "...in any formal inference the conclusion is implicitly contained in the premises, and affirms no absolutely new fact." Any theory of learning must observe this, so denying God, the only possible source of *a priori* concepts, would require a new form of logic whose conclusions are based on nothing at all. Atheists try to avoid this, hoping that complexity and obscurity can hide the fact that their epistemological assertions defy the laws of logic.

Comment: @PédeLeão this is not related to the question, but you basically say that atheism is logically absurd correct?

Comment: He tried to fix this himself by declaring "the keystone (Element) of all human knowledge and activity is belief (Glaube, or 'faith')" - this is referenced in the article you referred to. You might want to contemplate how he got there from the thesis you've proposed. I take it that you're an athiest - thats fine by me; but I don't think its ethical to cherry-pick a philosophers work merely to substantiate your own ideas. That seems wrong-headed to me in that it mis-characterises a mans work in order to bolster your own philosophical prejudices.

Comment: @MoziburUllah oh I'm definitely not an atheist, just trying to understand the "opposing" arguments :)

Comment: I feel Kant did not solve this problem. This would be why I would cite Kant as a signpost to the correct philosophy (imho) and not an example of it. His failure to ground knowledge may be why he is considered a Western thinker. Had he grounded it in direct experience he would have been banished from his tradition as a mystic.

Comment: @PeterJ I'm not entirely sure "direct experience" is inherently not comprehensivable in Western thought (just an example that popped into my head is Martin Buber, but I'm sure he's not the only one, it seems like an idea that'll be typical for existentialism and empiricism).

Comment: @YechiamWeiss: I don't understand your first sentence - and I'm a native English speaker. What do you mean by it? What do you mean by the word 'comprehensivable', I haven't come across this word before.

Comment: @YechiamWeiss: But [Martin Buber](http://www.iep.utm.edu/buber/) himself rejecting the label 'existentialism' by  "contrasting his emphasis on the whole person and 'dialogic' intersubjectivity with existentialist emphasis on 'monologic' self-consciousness".

Comment: @MoziburUllah yeah I'm sorry I wasn't sure if that's an English word :) I meant "comprehensive-able", being able to be comprehend. And sure, Buber rejected existentialism (although I'm not sure if entirely, I sense some existentialism in his writings, he's at the very least affected by that movement). But that doesn't make him a non-Western thinker, which is the generalization Peter made.

Comment: @YechiamWeiss: The word you're looking for is 'comprehensible'. I don't see that PeterJ made the remark that you're attributing to him about Martin Buber. He was talking about Kant and mentioned only that 'may be why he is considered a Western Thinker'.

Comment: @MoziburUllah thanks. But following Peter's line of thought (admittedly he can come and say I'm simply assuming the wrong interpretation, but it's also from previous conversations with him that I now he prefers Eastern thought), it seems that he goes from saying Kant is a Western thinker to saying no Western thinker will allow for such "direct experience".

Comment: @YechiamWeiss: Well, perhaps he has said to that you in some other conversation. But it certainly isn't visible in the thread above.

Comment: @MoziburUllah "had he grounded it in direct experience he would have been banished from his tradition as a mystic". But that's an irrelevant discussion to be honest. Maybe one day we'll write "interpreting PeterJ" book, but not anytime soon I think :)

Comment: And nor likely one on the thought of Yechiam Weiss soon ;). Or mine come to that.

Comment: Jacobi's assertion is incomplete, right?  We always have the Muenchausen trilemma.  Instead of infinite regress, there can be circularity, which is not the same thing, especially when one presumes vagueness, as Kant does.  Or there can simply be fiat (as pointed out by PeDeLeao).  Kant does not offer a foundation, he offers the lack of one, supported by analysis, largely because he accepts God as the real basis, and refuses to embed Him into his logic, because he is a Quietist, a sola fidei sort of Christian.

Comment: @jobermark in the Wikipedia article on Münchhausen Trilemma the "God as the basis" (I'd be honest, I'm not exactly sure that Kant really wanted to base his CPR on God at first, but needed to do it in later revisions) seems to fall under the "axiomatic argument", which is the solution to the foundationalism school. And as far as I understand it, any of the solutions in Münchhausen Trilemma are at the very least not ideal, if not simply bad.

Comment: OK, but he has chosen circularity over infinite regress.  He is happy to just be consistent, while explicitly ruling out anything foundational.  The foundation is in the noumena, which are explicitly inaccessible.  You can't say much louder "This is not a foundational theory" than to rule out the possibility of a foundational theory explicitly.  Also, he is a 'by faith alone' Christian, so one cannot take God as given or proven, because that would remove the need for faith.  So God may be the only available basis, in Kant's own mind, but cannot be a necessary one.

Comment: @YechiamWeiss - Your objection is not quite on the point. The reason stereotypically 'Western' philosophers do not understand what can be learned from investigating experience is that they do not investigate it. Where they do then there are exceptions. Nobody who claims membership of our tradition understands the origin and foundation of knowledge since this is deep stuff even for a Yoga practitioner. Russell calls it the most significant and difficult philosophical question.     .

Comment: @jobermark a) how exactly is Kant's theory circular? And I don't quite understand how basing on noumena is much different than First Mover. It's still foundational. I might need to read more Kant.

Comment: There is no circularity. @jobermark is assuming that there are only two options: infinite regress or circularity, but Kant's argument concerning the antinomies of reason showed that the grounds for infinite regress are based on an unjustified assumption. Therefore, there's a third option, namely, a series that terminates (as jobermark says, "The foundation is in the noumena."). Kant doesn't claim to prove that it terminates with God, but he shows that what reason demands describes God in many different ways.

Comment: OK, @PédeLeão . Do you understand what the 'tri' in trilemma means.  Do you see me list three options?  Do you read what you are commenting on before commenting?  I am not assuming there are two options.  But unknowable noumena gives us a sequence that ends in a roadblock.

Comment: As I see it, Kant takes internal consistency as a requirement for a true morality, because the truth that we can comprehend must be internally consistent, and truths about our own proper behavior should be comprehensible to us.  He proves (to his own satisfaction, not everyone's) that this minimal criterion is also a maximal one, and so constrains morality completely.  But the only way we know what internal consistency is is by knowing what we can and cannot make sense of.  If comprehensibility is a requirement for truth and truth is a requirement for comprehensibility...

Comment: At that point, we don't have a regress, we have a circular definition, which we just answer with an axiomatic system -- in this case the theory of categories.

Comment: @jobermark. Sorry. I didn't read all the comments. I'm posting my response in [The Symposium](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/538/the-symposium).

Answer (score 1):

Infinite regress problems are a result of a misunderstanding of epistemology. Epistemology is about how knowledge is created, how you can distinguish what ideas you should adopt and act on, and similar problems. Philosophers have commonly tried to solve this problem by saying there is a process called 'justification': a process that can make conclusions true or good or something like that - justificationism. An argument's conclusions are true if its premises and the rules applied applied to those premises are correct. So to show the conclusion of an argument is true, you must show the premises and rules are correct. To do that, you either assert by fiat that they are true, which proves nothing, or you make an another argument. If you make another argument, then you have the same problem as the original argument and you are no better off.

The notion that god somehow solves this problem doesn't make any sense. If you want to use god as a foundation then you either assert stuff about god by fiat, or you argue, which gives rise to the same problem.

Nevertheless, many philosophers ignore or deny or obfuscate this problem and spend their time arguing about induction or god or whatever. They argue endlessly about this issue and you can read vast piles of books about epistemology. People outside academic philosophy may occasionally think something along the lines that this is a difficult problem but progress is being made or something like that and point to some book or other that they haven't read or understood as being the state of the art.

One philosopher who didn't take this way out was Karl Popper. Popper bit the bullet and said that justification is impossible. Knowledge is created by noticing problems, making guesses about the solution, criticising the guesses and using the guesses that survive this process. The truth of those guesses is not guaranteed, nor is it probable or anything like that. But you can select ideas based solely on whether they survive criticism - that is, whether they leave relevant problems unsolved. For a guide to Popper's epistemological work, see

http://fallibleideas.com/books#popper

Comment: Isn't this a very old idea? I mean Socrates asked questions of the people in the polis and thereby got them to refine their ideas. Popper happened to be interested in Greek philosopy, and not just Socrates - Parmenides too. Yet by your reasoning it seems that one ought not to be interested in this and be merely interested in Popper, and just a small fraction of him; I mean his fallibilism; it strikes me as a very narrow outlook.

Comment: Making guesses and criticizing them presupposes concepts as well as some standard of evaluation, so Popper's theory is circular in nature. And nobody asserts God by fiat; rather, God has revealed His own existence in various ways. Kant demonstrated how God's role in our epistemology is logically consistent with reason.

Comment: @MoziburUllah I must say, to add to your comment (although not merely as old as the Greeks, but at least older then Popper) - I actually found the falsification idea in Schelling too.

Comment: @PédeLeão In the context of any specific argument some standard of evaluation and some ideas are used. But they are conjectures and can be refuted by criticism in subsequent arguments. There's no circularity because there's no attempt at justification. Your remarks about God don't address the problem I pointed out. Either Kant made an argument with rules and premises that could be wrong, or he assert God by fiat at some point. There is no third option.

Comment: @MoziburUllah Popper's fallibilist epistemology is directly relevant to this question. His writings about the pre-Socratics are not as relevant. Also, Popper's falliblism is more fully developed and explained than most fallibilist ideas before or since the time he wrote.

Comment: @alanf. The circularity lies in Popper's presupposing epistemic elements (standards and concepts or whatever his guesses consist of) to account for the origin of his epistemology. To avoid circularity, he needs to provide a non-epistemic origin for those guesses and standards. Concerning Kant, he didn't assert God as a premise but rather showed that the problem requires a solution beyond possible experience, namely, "a highest intelligence."

Comment: @alanf. However, we don't know God by arguments of reason nor by fiat. As I already said, God makes Himself known through self-revelation, especially as a consequence of repentance and faith. That would be your "third option."

Comment: @PédeLeão Popper doesn't have to account for the origin of his epistemology. Where it comes from is irrelevant, all that matters is whether it solves problems. You're judging Popper's ideas by a standard he rejects. A criticism would require explaining why that rejection is wrong, or explaining a problem Popper fails to solve. 
The argument about God that you describe presupposes that you have understood the problem and claims there is a unique solution. There is another unrefuted solution to that problem, so your understanding is wrong and your position is refuted.

Comment: @PédeLeão "God makes Himself known through self-revelation" You had an experience that you interpret in terms of god. Your interpretation of that experience may be wrong. Feelings, sensations, inner voices, a sense of wellbeing etc can all happen without the intervention of God. Your worldview requires totally eliminating that possibility since otherwise your views aren't justified, which is fatal for your position by its own standards. And you can't eliminate that possibility, so your position is wrong.

Comment: @alanf. You underestimate God if you believe that His ability to make Himself known somehow depends on me. And here's an [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circular_reasoning) that might help you understand what's wrong with Popper's argument.

Comment: @PédeLeão You said God makes himself known through self revelation, i.e. - through your thoughts and feelings. Therefore in every case, by your argument, God is known by people interpreting their thoughts and feelings, and the problem I have pointed out is relevant. Popper's ideas are not circular reasoning. Saying "I guess X. I guess Y. I guess X and Y are incompatible. I guess that means my ideas are problematic." is not circular and that's all that is required to make Popper's ideas work.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/73776/discussion-between-pe-de-leao-and-alanf).

Comment: @YechiamWeiss: Thats interesting. What exactly did Schelling say about falsification?

Comment: @MoziburUllah I'll quote from an excellent article I read by Arran Gare, where he also comments on that: "Schelling argued that the synthetic a priori knowledge of metaphysics is arrived at through dialectical construction which must engage with experience, and is not apodictic, but is fallible and subject to falsification and revision or replacement... He argued that an 'absolute hypothesis must bear its necessity within itself, but it must besides this, be brought to an empirical test. For inasmuch as all the phenomena of Nature cannot be deduced from this hypothesis as long as there is in..

Comment: ... the whole system of Nature a single phenomenon which is not necessary according to that principle, or which contradicts it, the hypothesis is thereby at once shown to be false, and from that moment ceases to have validity as a hypothesis' (Schelling, first outline). "